# How do I draw FontAwesome icons onto an image with ImageMagick convert command?

Tags: fonts, unicode, imagemagick

I have been writing text onto images with ImageMagick using the following method:

```
convert input.jpg \
  -fill 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)' \
  -font arial.ttf \
  -pointsize 140 \
  -gravity Center \
  -annotate +0+0 'SOME TEXT' \
  output.jpg
```

How can I pass Unicode values so that I can use icons from FontAwesome?

For example, I want to put the a play video icon (fa-play-circle `[&#xf144;]`) onto an image.

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf` to pass the correct Unicode value to `convert`.

Use the `-font` option to set the path to the FontAwesome font file.

Use `@-` to tell the `-annotate` option to take the text that is piped in.

```
env LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8 \
printf "\uF144"  | \
convert input.jpg \
-fill 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)' \
-font fontawesome-webfont.ttf \
-pointsize 140 \
-gravity Center \
-annotate +0+0 @- \
output.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

On Macos (10.15), this worked for me:

```
printf "\uF144"  | \
convert input.jpg \
-fill 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)' \
-font fontawesome-webfont.ttf \
-pointsize 140 \
-gravity Center \
-annotate +0+0 @- \
output.jpg
```

Setting `env LC_TYPE=en_US.utf8` then invoking `printf` produced: "`\uF144`".  Running `printf "\uF144"` without the environment UTF encoding, printed the `` character.

I'm not sure why, but I'm submitting this to augment Liam's correct answer above for Macos users.

Running the above successfully rendered the fontawesome icon on top of the input.jpg in the resultant output.jpg image.